# Extracting factors from an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I want to transform expressions into lists of elements. For example,

```
b*c + a*b*c /. Plus -> List /. Times -> List
```

> `{{b, c}, {a, b, c}}`

However, when the expression contains other functions such as

```
a*b*c + Cos[x - y] /. Plus -> List /. Times -> List
```

I get

> `{{a, b, c}, {Cos[x], Cos[y]}}`

I want to protect the arguments inside of functions. In the above example, I want to get

> `{{a, b, c}, {Cos[x - y]}}`

Any tips for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this example, I am assuming that the structure of your expressions will always be similar to your `input`:

```
input = a*b*c + Cos[x - y];
```

The method below is not exactly general.

First remove the outer-most `Plus`:

```
list = List @@ Expand[input]
(* {a b c, Cos[x - y]} *)
```

We then `Map` `Apply` over the list while being careful to avoid those expressions which are monomials:

```
If[Head@# === Times, List @@ #, {#}] & /@ list
(*  {{a, b, c}, {Cos[x - y]}} *)
```

#### Some explanations

For the purposes of making this answer actually more useful, I'll comment here about why the OP's method fails. Let's take it in steps.

First of all, `x - y` is interpreted as `x + (-1)*y`:

```
x - y // Fullform
(* Plus[x,Times[-1,y]] *)
```

and therefore the first replacement fails right off the bat, because this `Plus` gets replaced, too. Now,

```
Cos[x - y] /. Plus -> List
(* {Cos[x], Cos[y]} *)
```

This might seem strange, but it is a consequence of `Cos` being `Listable`:

```
Attributes @ Cos
(* {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected} *)
```

which means that it automatically `Thread`s over lists. In other words

```
Cos[x - y] /. Plus -> List
```

first becomes `Cos[{x, -y}]` which then becomes `{Cos[x], Cos[-y]}` which then automatically gets simplified to `{Cos[x], Cos[y]}`. To see this happen in action:

```
Cos[x - y] /. Plus -> List // Trace
```

[image]

Similar kinds of things can happen with replacements like `Times -> <head>`, so in general, I would recommend getting around this in other ways.

My solution was to use `Apply` instead of `ReplaceAll`. `Apply` can also be thought of as `ReplaceHead`:

```
Apply[f, g[x]]
(* f[x] *)
```

It's cleaner in this case, because the OP is interested only in replacing `Head`s of the expressions.

Comment: your definition of "input" seems to be wrong

Comment: @eldo. Right you are! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to admit a simple recursive approach.

```
terms[(Times | Plus)[args__]] := terms /@ {args}
terms[x_] := x
```

Then

```
terms[b c + a b c]
```

> `{{b, c}, {a, b, c}}`

```
terms[a b c + Sin[x] Cos[x - y]]
```

> `{{a, b, c}, {Cos[x - y], Sin[x]}}`

However,

```
terms[d/e Cos[x - y]]
```

> `{d, 1/e, Cos[x - y]}`

Will this last result will be acceptable? I can not make out from the question what is expected in this case.